# Geting doc from the firestore

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Hi I have a problem in my code and wanted to see if someone could help me. The problem I have is that I am trying to get the User from the Users collection of the firestore, this because to show the user's profile I need the User document.

Here you can see how I get the document, until there everything will be fine, then I put that when I click the button it makes a print of the user.username (userDoc.username). When I press the button if it gives me the correct username in the console but when I try to pass the user (userDoc) to my profileView I get an error. It tells me that it cannot find the userDoc.

Why?

[image]

```
 Button(action: {
                                showProfilePost.toggle()
                                let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(viewModel.post.ownerUid)

                                docRef.getDocument { snapshot, _ in
                                  // let userDoc = snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
                                   guard let userDoc = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return }
                                    // let userDoc = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
                                    
                                   // let userDoc = snapshot!.data(as: User.self)
                                    
                                   // dataToDisplay = userDoc
                                    print("\(userDoc.username)")
                                }
                                
                            }, label: {

                                Text("by  \(viewModel.post.ownerUsername)")


                            }).sheet(isPresented: $showProfilePost, content: {
                                    ProfileView(user: userDoc)
                                
                              //  Text(dataToDisplay.username)
                                
                            })
```

Here you can see the document I am trying to obtain:

[image: User Firestore]

User struct:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
let username: String
 @DocumentID var id: String?
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you declare "userDoc" as a local variable, this will not be accessable outside of its scope.
You were already trying something with "dataToDisplay". Use that, and trigger the
sheet when you have the data, something like this:

```
Button(action: {
    let docRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(viewModel.post.ownerUid)
    
    docRef.getDocument { snapshot, _ in
        // let userDoc = snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
        guard let userDoc = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self) else { return } // <-- local var
        // let userDoc = try? snapshot?.data(as: User.self)
        // let userDoc = snapshot!.data(as: User.self)
        dataToDisplay = userDoc  // <--- here
        print("\(userDoc.username)")
        self.showProfilePost.toggle()  // <--- trigger here
    }
    
}, label: {
    Text("by  \(viewModel.post.ownerUsername)")
})
    .sheet(isPresented: $showProfilePost, content: {
    ProfileView(user: dataToDisplay)  // <--- here, not userDoc
    
    //  Text(dataToDisplay.username)
})
```

Having said that, it is not a good idea to do async function calls to Firestore inside the Button. Re-think the structure of your code.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. This was my dataToDisplay variable:

@State var dataToDisplay: User

but I removed it because now in all views it asks for it and I only need it in this view. How do you